# Finding absolute minimum and maximum using lagrange mutlipliers?

Tags: partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

I have this function

$f(x,y)=3y^2-12x^2+1$ with the constraint $h(x,y)=x^2+y^2-x-2y+\frac54=0$.

First thing I do is write

$$3y^2-12x^2+1-λ(x^2+y^2-x-2y+\frac54)$$ which expands to $$3y^2-12x^2+1-λx^2-λy^2+λx+2yλ-\frac54.$$

The partial derivative with respect to $x$:

$-24x-2λx+λ=0$ where I get that $x= \dfrac λ{2(12+λ)}$.

The partial derivative with respect to $y$:

$6y-2yλ+2λ=0$ where I get that $y= -\dfrac λ{3-λ}$.

The partial derivative with respect to $λ$:

$$-x^2-y^2+x+2y$$

Now I know that I need to plug in the values of $x$ and $y$ in the $λ$ partial derivative which is $-x^2-y^2+x+2y$.

And here is where my problems arise.

On the answer sheet it states that $y= \dfrac λ{3-λ}$ (different from my answer since I get a negative $λ$ on the numerator).

Consequently, it states that I need to plug in the values of $x$ and $y$ NOT in the partial derivative of $λ$ (which I thought was always the case) but it states that I need to plug the values of $x$ and $y$ in the CONSTRAINT, hence 
$x^2+y^2-x-2y+\frac54$.

So my two questions are :

1) Why am I getting a different $y$ value?

2) Who is in the wrong here? Do I need to plug the $x$ and $y$ values in the partial derivative of $λ$ or in the constraint formula? Why?

Thanks in advance for the help. I have some learning disabilities involving maths so I would really appreciate your answers being as simple and clear as possible. Thanks!!

Comment: Your constraint is just a function, not a constraint. Is the constraint supposed to be $h(x,y)=0$?

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry i mistyped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\lambda$ partial derivative should have the $5/4$ still in it.  The constraint and $dL/d\lambda$ should be the same.
I usually add $\lambda$ times the constraint instead of subtracting it so my $\lambda$ would be the negative of yours.

Comment: Thanks for the help . I understand now that the constraint and dL/dλ should be the same. However, what do you mean when you say that you add λ to the constraint? Meaning can i choose if 3y²-12x²+1-λ(x²+y²-x-2y+5/4) or 3y²-12x²+1+λ(x²+y²-x-2y+5/4)? On what basis?

Comment: If you let $\mu=-\lambda$ then, the equations match.  In particular, the final values of $x$ and $y$ which are just numbers without $\lambda$ (or $\mu$) in them, should be the same.

Comment: Sorry for the question and thanks for the patience, but what is u in this case?

Comment: Mu is just another greek letter, to be used in the same role as lambda.

Comment: Thanks ! May i ask you one last question? A user said that in my case you cannot apply the Lagrange Multipliers technique because it needs that the restriction should define a derivable real variety, which is not the case.  Does this mean , in very , very poor words, that that since the constraint is equal to 0 and not a number other than 0 i need to add? Because if so everything would make sense to me

Comment: I hadn't spotted that.  There is only one point so derivatives don't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Your constraint

$$
x^2 + y^2 - x - 2 y + 5/4 = 0
$$

defines a feasible point region at $x = \frac 12, y = 1$

so the minimum is $f(\frac 12,1) = 1$

NOTE

In this case you cannot apply the Lagrange Multipliers technique because it needs that the restriction should define a derivable real variety, which is not the case.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! however i am not able to understand if  my y should be negative or positive? I understood how the partial derivative with respect to landa  is the same as the constriant, but i am confused on the negative/ positive sign of the equation . From what i understood i could add landa to the constriant instead of subtracting it? Why do i get a negative y value?

Comment: @BM97 In this case you cannot apply the Lagrange Multipliers technique because it needs that the restriction should define a derivable real variety, which is not the case.

Comment: In other words, does this imply that since the constraint is equal to 0 and not a number other than 0 i need to add?

Comment: @BM97 This means that the problem is ill posed. No solution is allowed from the Lagrange Multipliers technique.